# Python/Selenium: Identify current row in iteration of table

Tags: python, selenium

I have a function to find a specific row in a table based on one of the fields within.  Once I find the right row, I need to be able to return some identifier so I can navigate to that row later and extract other pieces of info.

My current function:

```
scantable = driver.find_element(By.ID, "sampleTable")    
def WaitForScan():
    for row in scantable.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr"):
        if "example.com" in row.text:
            if "complete" not in row.text:
                time.sleep(5)
                WaitForScan()
            else:
                itemid = ***This is the thing I need***
                print("Report is ready!")
                return itemid
```

I can grab a few attributes from "row" here, and the only notable/unique one I see is "row.id" - but this is like a hash value or something, not the "id" css value that Selenium can search for. This id value doesn't actually appear in the page code, so I'm guessing it's assigned from my console?  Can I leverage that somehow?  What's the best way to identify the row in a way that Selenium can find later?

Comment: Post the url you are trying to scrape.

Comment: Would it be possible to save the index position of the current row? If so, you can use `enumerate` to iterate over both the items and the indexes at the same time.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire_333 I can't, it's behind a login. This is a syntax/conceptual question, so the actual page shouldn't really matter.

Comment: @Anonymous4045 can you show me an example of how this would work?

Comment: @Ikarian it sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @Ikarian not sure how well code blocks work in comments, so I'll explain in text. Say you had a list `['apple', 'banana', 'pineapple']`. You can use `enumerate` to get both the fruit and the number in the list it is. E.g. `for index, fruit in enumerate(fruits): print(f'Fruit #{index} is a(n) {fruit}')`. If you were looking for, say, an apple, you would save the index of that item (eg `if fruit == 'apple': found = index`. You can then retrieve that from the original list by indexing it by `found`, so in this case `fruits[found]`

Comment: @Anonymous4045 Actually, I can probably do this with a simple counter built in to the iterator.  Then I can build the XPath using row[count].  Not a bad idea.  I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: @Ikarian yeah, that's essentially what `enumerate` does, but either should work

Comment: @Anonymous4045 checking back in to let you know that did the trick. For future googlers, seems to be a difference between the listed index and how it gets referenced that I haven't figured out, so start your counter at -1 :)